# w3.css vs bootstrap and which is more faster and better

Tags: bootstrap-4, w3.css

**w3.css faster or bootstrap and why ?**

**which one is better ?**

- Bootstrap uses JavaScript as well as CSS, but w3.css is a pure CSS
  framework. which helps in doing better SEO of your website too,
  because JavaScript is the enemy of SEO..

**What is SEO ?**

**Why javascript is enemy of SEO ?**

**why w3.css called pure css ?**

**and how bootstrap uses javascript ?**

> Explain it descriptive...

Comment: Please format your question better. My eyes really hurt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) ANSWER : w3.css OR Bootstrap ?

> Bootstrap uses JavaScript as well as CSS and W3.CSS is a modern CSS
>   framework with built-in responsiveness. It supports responsive mobile
>   first design by default, and it is smaller and faster than similar CSS
>   frameworks . which helps in doing better SEO of your website too,
>   because JavaScript is the enemy of SEO.

2) ANSWER : What is SEO?

> SEO stands for **Search engine optimization**  which consists in
>   increasing the Quantity & Quality of your website traffic through any
>   search engine results.

3) ANSWER : Why is javascript the enemy of SEO?

> It will also help visitors with JavaScript disabled or off, as well as
>   search engines that can't execute JavaScript yet.

4) ANSWER : Why W3.CSS called "pure CSS"?

> Because W3.css is not using JavaScript as well here.

5) ANSWER : How does Bootstrap use javascript?

> JavaScript is required for working on built in components like tabs,
>   dropdowns are defined in bootstrap.js file

Comment: You are 100% right but you can not get rid of bootstrap totally or you will need to do some styling by hand that contain a previously done code on bootstrap like multi level drop down menu that can't be done by **w3.css** this code might be easy compared to some other codes that need **javascript** to work. So i prefer using both but use **W3.CSS** as long as you can use it instead of bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

**w3.css faster or bootstrap and why ?**

Performance is depend size of your stylesheets. So browser have less work.
w3.css is css framework and it's lightweight and file size is low so it's fast compare to bootstrap.

https://www.quora.com/Which-framework-is-better-W3-CSS-or-Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap vs. W3.css

If you are a fan of W3Schools then use there CSS,W3.CSS if you don't use W3Schools use Bootstrap. I am using then both but also am using MyScript.css witch is a CSS language I made and once I get a domain name you can get MyScript.CSS too. [W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/) and [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com). I use Bootstrap because it's easy to use. So Bootstrap is good for people without W3Shools.